# Change default tty?

Tags: tty

On past computers, the X server would run on tty7 and I would end up there by default when starting my computer, while tty1 to tty6 would be text-only. On my current computer, running Ubuntu 18.04 (I know I need to upgrade at some point...), the X server is running on tty1 and tty2 with tty2 being the default, and tty 3-6 are text-only and tty7 non-existing. I find this confusing and often go to the wrong tty when switching. How can I change this so that there are 7 ttys and so that the X server only runs on tty7?

Comment: Learn the New Way,.

Comment: You'll need to be changing your default into the future (it's not a Ubuntu only change..) so I 2nd the *learn the new way* as it's been the *new* way now for years (and not just in Ubuntu based systems)

Comment: If you really need X on tty7 - install Ubuntu MATE and use it as before. It runs lightdm on tty7 as you like. Installing lightdm instead of gdm3 may be an option too.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to have X on tty7 is install LightDM login greeter using

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

and confirm its selection instead of gdm3.

Also please note that for example Ubuntu MATE keep the "X on tty7" tradition for you even in newest Ubuntu MATE 21.04.