# How do I start gdm3 on another console, like vt6?

Tags: 20.04

Ubuntu 20.04.2. I need tty1 as text and would like to set GUI to start on tty6. I can't find where I can set this. Does anybody know?

Comment: GDM has no simple way (at least, the simple ways no longer seem to work). There are other posts here on AU and elsewhere about how `FirstVT`,`NAutoVTs`, etc. no longer seem to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change default tty?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1335897/change-default-tty)

Comment: Does `startx` work? If it does, I will write it into an answer.

Comment: Yes startx works. But startx does not have complette GUI. Teamviewer will not work with startx.